# Run Service on Arbitrary Input Types (OSX Automator Workflow Service)

Tags: macos, service, workflow, automator, uti

I want to create a new Service (OSX `runWorkflowAsService`) that uses a custom `InputTypeIdentifier` value. Is there any way to make this happen?

For example, a hypothetical workflow's `document.wflow` file (generated by Automator) looks like this:

```
<key>workflowMetaData</key>
<dict>
    <key>serviceInputTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.Automator.fileSystemObject</string>
    ...
</dict>
```

But I want (e.g.) this to be possible:

```
    <key>serviceInputTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ApplicationBundle</string>
```

From trial-and-error, it seems that only predefined `com.apple.Automator` UTIs are acceptable to the system workflowServiceRunner. Is there a workaround?